# Removing div wrapper container of paragraph field and get only the plain text in twig

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have a paragraph template in my custom theme as `paragraph--home-page-carousel.html` and when I write like this

```
<span class="car-spec">{{ content.field_home_slide_snippet[0]|raw }}</span>
```

I get in HTML source code this

```
 <div>
    <span class="car-spec">
    FIELD CONTENT
    </span>
</div>
```

what should I do to remove the div wrapper?

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't do `{{ content.field_home_slide_snippet[0]|raw }}`. You should do `{{ content.field_home_slide_snippet }}` and edit the twig template for `field--field-home-slide-snippet.html.twig` to have no HTML wrappers. Copy `field.html.twig` to your theme and edit as needed.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin but I tried this and still get the "div".

Comment: Did you also edit the paragraph twig and remove the div? If you enable twig debugging it will tell you what templates are being used.

Comment: Yes I removed from the both. I enabled devel and twig debug and tried these templates

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **strip tags filter** : `{{ some_html|striptags('<span>') }}`
Assuming the html is dynamically wrapped by the `<div>` tag, this will strip the `<div>` tag and leave the `<span>` tag.

so

```
{% set mycontent %}
    {{ content.field_home_slide_snippet }}
{% endset %}
{{ mycontent|striptags('<span>') }}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

`{{ content.field_home_slide_snippet.0["#context"].value }}`

or enable devel module and then use

`{{ kint(content.field_home_slide_snippet) }}`

to see where is value that you need.